# Get Status of Socket IO Server

Tags: node.js, testing, socket.io

I need to create a Socket IO server and wait until it is up and running (for running some tests). I've looked through the documentation but can't find any event or callback for creating a server that notifies you when it's up and running (or if it's experiencing any errors). Is there a way to monitor the status of a Socket IO server?

P.S. - To be clear, I'm not interested in monitoring the http.Server that Socket IO runs on top of, I want to know about Socket IO specifically (unless I'm misunderstanding, and those two things are 100% equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar tests in the past with `socket.io-client` and `ava`.

Basically what I do is I use `socket-io.client` to connect to my `socket.io` server and I use the events to handle my workflow.

```js
import test from `ava`
import io from `socket.io-client`

let socket

test.before(async t => {
  socket = io(`http://localhost:3000`)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    socket.on('connect', resolve)
    socket.on('error', reject)
  })
})

test(`My test`, async t => {
  // socket.io must be connected here
  // otherwise an error may have been raised!
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is helpful, thanks! But is there no way to ask Socket IO what its status is? I can see that being useful outside of tests too (e.g. I'd like my server logs to tell me that everything has been initialized correctly, is that not an option with Socket IO?)

Comment: I believe I remember seeing a ping event in a previous version, but can't find it anymore... I think you could implement one yourself though... I would do it only for tests purposes maybe implementing a listener in the server that when triggered from client side it only job is to ping back!

Comment: Also, in the ava example, mind that socke.on('diconnect', () => {}) will get fired if anything happens server-side interrupting the socket connection (server down, for example).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that would help here. A ping would work if I wanted external processes to check in on the server. I want the server to report what it's own status is...